# Unable to build flux repl in WSL

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, influxdb-2

I am trying to build the flux repl into wsl in Window 10

I followed the instructions as per the repo (https://github.com/influxdata/flux/#requirements)

When I run the build command

```
$ go build ./cmd/flux
```

I get an error

```
# pkg-config --cflags  -- flux
Package flux was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `flux.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'flux' found
pkg-config: exit status 1
```

I couldn't find a flux.pc in the repo.
**How do I fix it?**

Answer (score 1):

After search I needed to run the following command before building.

export PKG_CONFIG=./pkg-config.sh